# MPI_Scatter invalid pointer error : Maybe something wrong with the MPI_Type_vector

Tags: c, mpi

I'm writing a program to scatter a matrix shaped 84*84 into 4 process. Each process receive a sub-matrix shaped 84*21. It look like this:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
```

Then, I should create a new datatype to represent such discrete data form. I use the `MPI_Type_vector` and `MPI_Type_create_resized` to create such datatype. However, the invalid pointer exception was raised during in the `MPI_Scatter` function, and I don't think I've done any incorrect memory operations. Is there any trap or something?

By the way, the problem only occurs when n is larger than 80.

Here is the code.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
/*
 * compile command:
 * mpiicc -g -c matvectmul_col_mul_version.c -o matvectmul_col_mul_version.o
 * mpiicc  matvectmul_col_mul_version.o -o matvectmul_col_mul_version
 *
 * run command:
 *      srun -n 4 -l ./matvectmul_col_mul_version 84
 */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        int n = atoi(argv[1]);
        double *loc_matrix = NULL;
        int my_rank, comm_sz;
        MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
        MPI_Comm comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
        MPI_Comm_size(comm, &comm_sz);
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &my_rank);
        int m = n / comm_sz;
        MPI_Datatype vect_mpi_t;

        loc_matrix = (double*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));
        double *matrix = NULL;
        double *vector = NULL;
        if (my_rank == 0) {
                matrix = (double*)malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
                memset(matrix,0,n*n*sizeof(double));
        }
        MPI_Datatype mpi_tmp_t;
        MPI_Type_vector(n,m,n,MPI_DOUBLE,&mpi_tmp_t);
        MPI_Type_create_resized(mpi_tmp_t,0,m*sizeof(double),&vect_mpi_t);
        MPI_Type_commit(&vect_mpi_t);

        MPI_Scatter(matrix,1,vect_mpi_t,loc_matrix,n*m,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        //MPI_Scatter(matrix,1,vect_mpi_t,loc_matrix,1,vect_mpi_t,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD); Also not work

        if (my_rank == 0) {
                free(matrix);
        }
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
}
```

And here is the error information:

```
srun: error: cn003: task 0: Aborted (core dumped)
0: *** Error in `/home/2016011275/workspace/HW1/task2/./matvectmul_col_mul_version': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001917840 $
**
0: ======= Backtrace: =========
0: /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7c503)[0x7fce91e51503]
0: /apps/rm/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.128/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/libmpi.so.12(+0x2f08ab)[0x7fce92fc68ab]
0: /apps/rm/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.128/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/libmpi.so.12(+0x4d97c6)[0x7fce931af7c6]
0: /apps/rm/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.128/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/libmpi.so.12(+0x4de03f)[0x7fce931b403f]
0: /apps/rm/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.128/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/libmpi.so.12(PMPI_Scatter+0x360)[0x7fce931b2c00]
0: /home/2016011275/workspace/HW1/task2/./matvectmul_col_mul_version[0x400e63]
0: /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fce91df6b35]
0: /home/2016011275/workspace/HW1/task2/./matvectmul_col_mul_version[0x400ae9]
0: ======= Memory map: ========
0: 00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 00:29 11118498385                        /home/2016011275/workspace/HW1/task2/matvectmul_col_mu
l_version
0: 00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 00:29 11118498385                        /home/2016011275/workspace/HW1/task2/matvectmul_col_mu
l_version
0: 00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 00:29 11118498385                        /home/2016011275/workspace/HW1/task2/matvectmul_col_mu
l_version
```

Comment: You have not checked the return value from any of the MPI functions, or from `malloc`. Aside: you have not used `loc_vector` or `vector`.

Comment: Does it work if replace `vect_mpi_t` with the explicit sizes in the `MPI_Scatter` call?

Comment: `vect_mpi_t` represents a subset of `matrix` but cannot be used for `loc_matrix` (you need an other data type for that, or you can simply receive `m*n MPI_DOUBLE`)

Comment: @WeatherVane The return values of all MPI functions are 0, and the malloc function do return a non-NULL pointer. The loc_vector&vector are just something I forget delete in my question, and I've been update the question.

Comment: @ptb @Gilles Gouaillardet  It will also not work if I replace the Scatter function with `MPI_Scatter(matrix,1,vect_mpi_t,loc_matrix,n*m,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);` However, for `MPI_Scatter(matrix,n*m,MPI_DOUBLE,loc_matrix,n*m,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);` It works,(but this scatter order is not I want.)

Comment: @TobyMao fwiw, the code works for me. how did you test it ?

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet  I use mpiicc(icc (ICC) 18.0.0 20170811) to compile the c program, and then use srun(slurm 17.02.7) to execute. And now I'm guessing it is caused by some bug of the platform itself. I've changed the `MPI_Scatter` into `MPI_Scatterv` and it works.

Comment: Could be because of an incorrect optimization. Using a derived datatype and recvcount=1 could be a workaround.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue with IntelMPI and `srun`. The error does not occur with Open MPI and srun, or with IntelMPI with `mpirun`, so I guess this is some kind of bad interaction between IntelMPI and `srun`, so I suggest you report this to Intel support.